# Declaring same module twice: duplicate ressources

Tags: terraform

I am working on a 100% terraform project and I am trying to use the output value from one module into another module. Based on different StackOverflow posts, the most popular way to import the output from module `a` to module `b` is to reference the module `a` inside module `b` such as:

**modules/b/main.tf**

```
module "a" {
  source = "./modules/a"
}
```

After that, you can access output variables from module `a` inside module `b`.

**My project structure**

```
├── main.tf # declaring all my modules here
├── modules
│   ├── accounts
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── organizations
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf # the var. that I wanna use in accounts
│       └── variables.tf
├── providers.tf
├── variables.tf
└── versions.tf
```

So my issue is I am declaring all my modules in my `main.tf`

**main.tf**

```
module "organizations" {
  source = "./modules/organizations"
}

module "accounts" {
  source = "./modules/accounts"
}
```

However, I need to use one output of module/organizations into module/accounts. And the only way I found to do that is to have (another) organizations module in my `modules/accounts/main.tf`

**modules/accounts/main.tf**

```
module "organizations" {
  source = "../organizations"
}

resource "aws_organizations_account" "this" {
  name      = "uuuu"
  email     = "udduu@gmail.com"
  parent_id = module.organizations.sandbox_organizational_unit_id #HERE
}
```

But since I already have an `organizations` module in my `main.tf`, it's creating/deleting resources in my `organization` module twice.

**organisations/main.tf**

```
data "aws_organizations_organization" "root" {}

locals {
  root_id = data.aws_organizations_organization.root.roots[0].id
}

resource "aws_organizations_organizational_unit" "sandboxs" {
  name      = var.aws_sandboxs_unit_name
  parent_id = local.root_id
}
```

**organisations/outputs.tf**

```
output "sandbox_organizational_unit_id" {
  value       = aws_organizations_organizational_unit.sandboxs.id
  description = "ID of the Sandboxs OU"
  sensitive   = false
}
```

Comment: You need to define `output`s in the first module and `variable`s in the second module to pass all the information around that is needed.

Comment: I already have the output in my first module but how do I reference it using variables on the second module?

Comment: `module "organizations" { [...] some_variable = module.accounts.some_output }`

Comment: that's exactly what I currently have but since I declared the same module `organizations` in my root `main.tf` as well, I have duplicated ressources everytime I apply

Comment: Then remove it in one place, *I* do not care where the organization module is created but it should probably only be declared once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of your modules should explicitely refer to the other one. Instead, they should declare what kind of variable they expect as input (via a `variable` key), and what output they provide in return (via the `output` key)

Then in your main.tf, you can plug everything together:

```
module "organizations" {
  source = "./modules/organizations"
  some_variable = module.accounts.some_output
}

module "accounts" {
  source = "./modules/accounts"
}
```

- in "organizations",  a `some_variable` must be declared as input: `variable some_variable {}`
- in `accounts` , a `some_output` must be declared as output: `output some_output { value = ... }`